# ListView doesn't show refreshed content

Tags: java, android, listview, refresh, baseadapter

I have a custom adapter which extends from **BaseAdapter**..

> **Custom adapter code :**

```
public class SearchListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private JsonArray searchResults;

    public SearchListViewAdapter(Context context, JsonArray searchResults) {
        this.searchResults = searchResults;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return searchResults.count();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return searchResults.get(position);
    }

    /*public ListAdapter updateResults(JsonArray results) {
        searchResults = results;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return null;
    }*/

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        JsonObject searchResult = (JsonObject)getItem (position);
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_search_result, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtFullName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.FullName);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtFullName.setText(searchResult.getString ("FirstName") + searchResult.getString ("LastName"));

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtFullName;
    }
}
```

> **Activity code :**

```
// After displaying the list in an onPostExecute Method of an AsyncTask class 
// I call another async task : BarcodeAction by giving the param : records
new BarcodeAction(records).execute("");

private class BarcodeAction extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JsonArray> {

    private JsonArray records;

    public BarcodeAction(JsonArray result)
    {
        this.records = result;
    }

    @Override
    protected JsonArray doInBackground(String... params) {

        // Processing... if it's success the onPostExecute method receive : records
        if (resultType.equals("success"))
            return records;

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final JsonArray records) {
        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewSearchResults);

        // EDIT : notifyDataSetChange doesn't work
        SearchListViewAdapter svla1 = new SearchListViewAdapter(SearchActivity.this, records);
        lv1.setAdapter(svla1);
        svla1.notifyDataSetChanged();   


        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                JsonObject response = (JsonObject)o;

                SearchActivity.VISITOR_BARCODE = response.getString("Barcode");

                new BarcodeAction(records).execute("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But my list is not getting refreshed..

Do you have any idea about this ? Thnak you.

Comment: where is `resultType` defined?

Comment: @Emmanuel thank you. I've just dropped the code because to short the post it's the result of a REST Api call... and the `return records` definitely works

Answer (score 0):

getItemId() should return unique value for each entry in the list. Try returning position only.

Comment: @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position; // Change 0 --> position
    }

Comment: Excuse me, but that's not my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main cause is **missing calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` method**.

In fact, your "activity code" is not exactly the activity but a asnyctask that fetch the data. A more common way to use adaper is having a Adaper in your activty along with ListView. In your fetching-data-method(asynctask or loader), call the adaper's change underlying data interface to change the data, and call the adaper's `notifyDataSetChanged()` method.

A bit psudeo-code may looks like:

Adaper:

```
public class SearchListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
     private JsonArray searchResults;

     ......

     public setDataSet(JsonArray newData) {
         searchREsults = newData;
     }

     ......
}
```

Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    ListView mResultListView;
    SearchListViewAdaper mResultViewAdaper;

    @override 
    OnCreate(...) {
          ......
        //init mResultListView
        mResultListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.xxxx);
        mResultViewAdaper = new SearchListViewAdapter();
        mResultListView.setAdapter(mResultViewAdaper);
        ......
    }
    ......
}
```

AsyncTask:
    public fetchDataTask extends AsyncTask {
        ......

```
    onPostExecute(JsonArray records) {
      mResultViewAdaper.setDataSet(records);
      // IMPORTANT: notify data change
      mResultViewAdaper.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: thank you. But it doesn't work.. I've updated my code adding `notifyDataSetChanged()` and still nothing...

Comment: I just did almost exactly what you did in a simpler version, and it worked for me. Check the code at [here](https://github.com/demote/androidTest). If you notice anything odd, let me know. Wish this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Yes it should work, but it's about refreshing. I cannot see where is there an update of the List and a `notifyDataSetChanged`.. Am I wrong ?

Comment: In fact, the code example in this answer and the code in github uses different ways to refresh the list. The example above in the answer uses the same adaper all the time, when you get some new data, you set it to the (prior and only) adapter, that's when a `notifyDataSetChanged` is need. Meanwhile, in the code you give, you are trying to create a new adapter whenever some new data is available, therefore no adapter's data is changed and `notifyDataSetChanged` is not needed.

Comment: As for the code I implement according to yours, the listview **CAN** refresh. Therefore I am a little confused. So, I would suggest you to check again what is missing OR you can refactor your code using the same adapter and change its dataset when you have new data (which is the way I have used for many times).